# How to show information of myself using kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to confirm information of the authenticated user and assigned role and assigned cluster role. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

> information of the authenticated user

When you see [Define clusters, users, and contexts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#define-clusters-users-and-contexts), you realize you need to get the information associated with a defined *context*.

```
kubectl config --kubeconfig=config-demo use-context dev-frontend
kubectl config --kubeconfig=config-demo view --minify
```

> The output shows configuration information associated with the dev-frontend context:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: fake-ca-file
    server: https://1.2.3.4
  name: development
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: development
    namespace: frontend
    user: developer
  name: dev-frontend
current-context: dev-frontend
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: developer
  user:
    client-certificate: fake-cert-file
    client-key: fake-key-file
```

> assigned role and assigned cluster role.

You can list roles for all users or clusters, but you still need to parse the result to get the one for *a* user or *a* cluster.
Example: "[kubectl and seeing (cluster)roles assigned to subjects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43186611/6309)".