# How to list my current RBAC roles and groups I belong to?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I authenticated to kubernetes cluster, how can I view my RBAC roles and groups attached to my current account?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. If you feel the question is on-topic, then see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: AFAIK there is nice `kubectl` plugin - [rakkess](https://github.com/corneliusweig/rakkess)

Comment: @jww why do vote for closing? they are plenty of similar questions to this and they are not being voted for closing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Found better tool

this tool looks way better than rakkess
exactly what I was looking for

https://github.com/reactiveops/rbac-lookup

In the simplest use case, rbac-lookup will return any matching user, service account, or group along with the roles it has been given.

```
rbac-lookup rob

SUBJECT                   SCOPE             ROLE
rob@example.com           cluster-wide      ClusterRole/view
rob@example.com           nginx-ingress     ClusterRole/edit
The wide output option includes the kind of subject along with the source role binding.
```

```
rbac-lookup ro --output wide

SUBJECT                   SCOPE             ROLE                SOURCE
User/rob@example.com      cluster-wide      ClusterRole/view    ClusterRoleBinding/rob-cluster-view
User/rob@example.com      nginx-ingress     ClusterRole/edit    RoleBinding/rob-edit
User/ron@example.com      web               ClusterRole/edit    RoleBinding/ron-edit
ServiceAccount/rops       infra             ClusterRole/admin   RoleBinding/rops-admin
```

Comment: You can use these tools and more via [krew](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/krew)

Answer (score 4):

## Follow the below steps

1. Install go and verify that it is present

```
master $ echo $GOPATH
/opt/go
```

2. Create and Verify

```
master $ mkdir -p $GOPATH/bin
```

3. Install rakkess

```
curl -Lo rakkess.gz https://github.com/corneliusweig/rakkess/releases/download/v0.2.0/rakkess-linux-amd64.gz && \
  gunzip rakkess.gz && chmod +x rakkess \
  && mv rakkess $GOPATH/bin/
```

4. List the privileges in a specific namespace

```
rakkess --namespace <namespace-name>
```

5. You should see the output in the below format

```
master $ rakkess -n kube-system
NAME                                            LIST  CREATE  UPDATE  DELETE
bindings                                              ✔
configmaps                                      ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
controllerrevisions.apps                        ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
cronjobs.batch                                  ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
daemonsets.apps                                 ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
daemonsets.extensions                           ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
deployments.apps                                ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
deployments.extensions                          ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
endpoints                                       ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
events                                          ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
events.events.k8s.io                            ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
horizontalpodautoscalers.autoscaling            ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
ingresses.extensions                            ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
jobs.batch                                      ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
limitranges                                     ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
localsubjectaccessreviews.authorization.k8s.io        ✔
networkpolicies.extensions                      ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
networkpolicies.networking.k8s.io               ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
persistentvolumeclaims                          ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
poddisruptionbudgets.policy                     ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
pods                                            ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
podtemplates                                    ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
replicasets.apps                                ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
replicasets.extensions                          ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
replicationcontrollers                          ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
resourcequotas                                  ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
rolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io          ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io                 ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
secrets                                         ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
serviceaccounts                                 ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
services                                        ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
statefulsets.apps                               ✔     ✔       ✔       ✔
```

Comment: thanks for answer! I checked out rakkess already, but that shows what I can do, the 'verbs', but how to list roles attached to me?

Comment: there is no direct way. check this link --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186611/kubectl-and-seeing-clusterroles-assigned-to-subjects

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant?

kubectl get role -o yaml
kubectl get rolebinding -o yaml

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).