# GKE RBAC giving unlimited access to namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, devops, google-kubernetes-engine, rbac

hi everyone i am using GKE and i am trying use RBAC and restrict other user to a specific namespace.
here is my RBAC policy

```html
  apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: team-1
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: team-1
  name: team_1-rw
rules:
- apiGroups: ["extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["deployments"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: team-1
  name: team_1-binding
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: abc@example.com
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: team_1-rw
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

after applying this policy when try to login from user id and do `kubectl get deployments` , it does not restrict me to check deployments in the default namespace.it should only work for me `team-1 namespace` but it gives unlimited access to other namespaces aswell Also i have given the user kubernetes engine viewer permission in IAM

Comment: [RoleBinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding) is always bound to some namespace. If you have access to other namespaces, it has to be done via `ClusterRoleBinding`

Comment: yeah the problem is i dont want access to other namespaces with rolebinding. currently i am able to get access to unlimited namespaces

Comment: You probably didn't understand. Technically, you can't access other namespaces with `RoleBinding`, that's sole purpose of `ClusterRoleBinding`. Your subject (user) has more likely some CluserRoleBinding associated already that you are not aware of.

Comment: how to know if user have 'ClusterRoleBinding' enabled and how to disable that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kubectl and seeing (cluster)roles assigned to subjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186611/kubectl-and-seeing-clusterroles-assigned-to-subjects)